# Choosing the iAd banner

Tags: ios, iad

I am new to iAd. I used iAd for the first time in one of my apps .. and I didn't like the type of ads that was shown in my app. Is there anyway to choose which ads or banners can appear in my app? 
or at least which category of ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to add content (e.g. kid apps or car ads), you don't have a choice in which type of ads are displayed to the user. There does seem to be some tailoring of ads from Apple based on user data from app download analytics but that's entirely opaque to developers adopting iAd.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs which are provided with iAd lets you show either **banners** either **interstitial** ads (which is an ad displayed on all the screen).